# 'Then By' usage with different number of criterias

Tags: c#, sorting, sql-order-by, criteria

I am writing a C# program that allows user to specify sorting criterias. For example, the user can sort only by "serviceName", or add several other criterias like "isHD" or "isGood". What I ask is, I want to use '.Then By' statement but the user determines how many times I need to write it.

Is there any way that I can get some  flexibility on the number of criteria depending on a switch/case block?
e.g

```
List.OrderBy(t => t.name)
List.OrderBy(t => t.isHD).ThenBy(t => t.name)
List.OrderBy(t => t.isGood).ThenBy(t => t.name).ThenBy(t => t.isHD)
```

Also the order of these criteria will be chosen by the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use generic method:

```
    public List<T> SortBy<T>(List<T> list, params Func<T, object>[] selectors)
    {
        var ordered = list.OrderBy(selectors[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < selectors.Count(); i++)
        {
            ordered= ordered.ThenBy(selectors[i]);
        }
        return ordered.ToList();
    }
```

run it:

```
SortBy(List, x=>x.name, x=>x.isHD, x=>x.isGood)
```

which will do:

```
List.OrderBy(x=>x.name).ThenBy(x=>x.isHD).ThenBy(x=>x.isGood)
```

can be improved by checking if selectors where passed

Comment: @user2747001: You can also use the above code by simply passing in an array of selectors that you composed ahead of time from user input.

Comment: Since the `ordered` variable is not assigned in the loop body, none of the `ThenBy` orderings will be applied.

i.e. the loop body should read: `ordered = ordered.ThenBy(selectors[i]);`

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work exactly like that, unless you want to pass multiple selectors that select the exact same type. If you want to pass different type selectors, then it'll have to be `Func<T, object>` and without the second type parameter `TU`.

Comment: As patryk wrote, there is no generic params support in C# :-)

Comment: @user27470001 now it's <T, object> read about Func on msdn, it's used here to get property value from object, having this func you can call it passing object and get property you want

Comment: Alright, thank you all, I guess this answer works. Now I will read about Func as you said. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the result of applying the first sort-order (i.e. `OrderBy`) to a variable of type `IOrderedEnumerable` and then call `ThenBy` in a loop assigning to the same variable as many times as required.